# pass a 2 dimensional array to a funtion in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass a 2 dimensional array:

```
events = [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2014-09-01'
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2014-09-07',
        end: '2014-09-10'
    }
];
```

to a display function:

```
function display(events){
    alert(display the matrix);
};
```

but it doesn't work, it displays just "objects" and not the value of the objects

Comment: It looks like you are already passing a two-dimensional array to a function in javascript. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: yes but i want to know what is the exact way to do it, because it didnt work for me

Comment: The passing should be fine If you are determining success based on the alert that will not work. Is that what the problem is?

Comment: it displays just "objects" and not the value of the objects.

Comment: An object is a complex data structure. JS doesn't know how you want it displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to loop through your array. Your array contains objects so you need a second loop to access the properties of the objects.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/80upo2yy/1/)

```
function display(ar){
    for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){//loop through array ar
        for(k in ar[i]){//loop through the properties of each object
            console.log(k+': '+ar[i][k]) //output too JS console (press F12)
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your display function just iterate over the elements in events.

Your function has to look somewhat like the following:

```
function display(e){
    for(i=0; i < e.length; i++){
    // do stuff, e.g.:
        alert(e[i]["title"]);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
display(myEvents);
```

where "myEvents" is your two dimensional array.